# Export Data from CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I am interacting with the cloudkit dashboard and looking at data collected by my app.

How can I export all the data from the dashboard (data-> csv or json) so that I can do some analytics on it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38279009/is-there-any-option-to-export-all-cloud-kit-data

Comment: The link above doesn't have information OP asked, which is reasonable: so far in Sept 2017 I don't think there's a way to export data as a way you desired. The only viable option would be writing your own exporting app. The link does contain information about how to do that.

Comment: As of **2018**, it's still not possible to export your data from CloudKit directly. But querying all your records and writing the results to a CSV file is fairly easy to do in Swift.

Comment: Still the same situation now, in mid-February 2019...

Comment: And now it's March 2020! I think @Sascha's comment may be correct. Time to roll our own.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Apple will ever provide an export feature.
The system is capable to collecting more than 40 events per second. This could very quickly be massive amount of data.
Instead there is a possibility to query the system via an API, so you can build an external website to query your results and possibly export your data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I export my iCloud data on my Mac using this wonderful DB browser called DB Browser for SQLite.

I run my app on Simulator. The app syncs with iCloud and downloads both public and private databases. Once the sync is complete I have all the data on my simulator. The data is essentially in SQlite format stored in a file which I locate using command in my app:

`print("\(NSHomeDirectory())/Library/Application Support/")`

and the result is something like:

`/Users/zeeshan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/34A4ADC6-1B67-4339-B67F-C4B6DDA46B07/data/Containers/Data/Application/E8F9486B-B40B-47D0-84C1-1043241E68EA/Library/Application Support/`

And here `.sqlite` file is saved. In my case I have two files, `private.sqlie` and `public.sqlite` which is how I have named them in my code.

Now I open these files in DB Browser for SQLite. And then rest is simple, just export the opened file as you would do for any SQlite file.

Attached are the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]